# Why the package restore failed in my WebApplication and how to deal with it?

Tags: asp.net-core

I built a webapplication with asp.net core, the nuget manager informed me that there are updates for the packages. But they failed, both the AspNetCore and the StaticFiles one. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Try changing the `TargetFramework` to `netcoreapp2.0` in your applications *.csproj* file first, then try applying these updates.

Comment: Can you show your project .csproj file? Right click and select Edit project properties. Most like you are targeting dotnetcore1.* version. You need to change it to dotnetcore2.0

Comment: Your Visual Studio is up to date? When dotnetcore 2.0 was lauched, the visual studio tooling was updated.